# Why was my answer deleted as 'not an answer' when it answered the question?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

One of my answers was deleted as low quality. A reviewer said "This does not provide an answer to the question."
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20245109

My answer was one line of code which indicates how to fix the critical problem described in the OP (object reference is not in scope) using a self-identifier "as this". (This is described in the original question as in the error message "The value, namespace, type or module 'this' is not defined.").

The people who voted for deletion do not have F# listed as a top tag, and presumably do not understand my line of code, and therefore lacked the expertise to decide whether it answers the question or not.

Judge me by my size, do you?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't deleted for not having an explanation. That I would be happy with. It was deleted for not being an answer, which is not correct. It did answer the question.

Comment: Please, meta is not a place to rant about possibly questionable moderation occurrences. If an issue is particularly distressing, you could raise a custom mod flag to have a moderator look at what's happened on that post. You are also advised to not call out specific users by name. And anyways, this is specific to Stack overflow, so would be a little less off-topic on stack overflow meta.

Comment: Seriously, your even had to type `notenoughcharacters` to submit this one liner. Please read [help/answer] and explain your answers, the fact you had to write garbage to submit should have trigger something in your mind about why we require a minimum number of characters per answer.

Comment: Animuson deleted his answer, but it seems you added fillter text to hit the minimum character limit.  If that's true, that, by itself, is a very good reason to delete it.  The minimum character limit is there for a reason.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie: If a diamond mod edited your question, it's not really a good idea to undo that.

Comment: I mostly agree with the comments and answers here (especially Jon Clements) but +1 for the good faith attempt to read the help docs, find meta, and work with the community on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Your answer was of low quality, containing a poorly formatted code sample mixed with the single word "type" which formed the explanation.

You also used "notenoughcharacters" as a way of circumventing a minimum size limit.

Work with the site engines' rules, not against them.

Comment: The code sample was not poorly formatted, and did not contain the word "text".

Comment: @CharlesRoddie: On your second point you are correct. But not the first.

Comment: What is poorly formatted about the code?

Comment: @CharlesRoddie But what do you want us to do here? You can easily go ahead and answer the question with a little more text. Why post on Meta?

Comment: Mode specifically, why the main Meta? This is about a certain incident on stack overflow, and doesn't concern other sites. Actually, it doesn't even deeply affect the functioning of stack overflow either

Comment: @CharlesRoddie: I like to answer questions in a brief a way as possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213172/logical-operators-precedence-in-c/51213204#51213204), but you cross a line here. Surely you can see that?

Comment: @Chair: I'm not sure about that. This is more about contributors on a site being empowered to use the moderator tools on questions on topics in which they are not experts.

Comment: @ModusTollens: That's exactly what I'm saying!

Comment: @Bathsheba that could potentially be an implication. But the phrasing of this question is just like a rant and he specifically calls out the qualification of the 4 users who reviewed his post. If he made a more general argument that we need to ensure that reviewers have a certain degree of expertise in the specific tag, then it's a constructive post which belongs on the main meta. In such a post, he could feel free to cite his own experience. But the heading "judge me by my size?" doesn't have a constructive "let's make things better" vibe.

Comment: I saw that my answer was deleted, for a reason that was not correct, and could not comment on the answer or the review, and google directed me to post on a "meta" to request undeletes. So it's no suprise I ended up here. Maybe it was the wrong meta. And maybe the answer would have been deleted on other grounds.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie you realise you can edit your answer to put a bit more detail in so it's not got place holder characters, and then vote to undelete your answer (which you can do unilaterally as it didn't receive proper delete votes - just make sure you edit it first because undeletion will cause a mod-flag to be raised to review it - so if it's still not great - a mod will end up deleting it soon anyway and you won't be able to undelete it again), right?

Comment: @JonClements that's useful thanks.

Comment: @Bathsheba `type` is a keyword within the programming language used, so this is a valid line of code.